# Cloudflare page rules for removing multiple trailing slash

Tags: cloudflare

Cloudflare page rules for removing multiple trailing slash

I want to set up the below things.

`https://domain.com//` OR `https://domain.com//` OR `https://domain.com///` OR onwards

are redirecting to `https://domain.com/`

How can I set up this using the Cloudflare page rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be quicker to set that in your webserver(Nginx) virtual host than doing it on Cloudflare.

Add below in your Nginx config:

```
if ($request_uri ~* "\/\/") {
  rewrite ^/(.*)      https://$host/$1    permanent;
}
```